# Accessing report info from reports stored in the new Fine-Grained Sharing Folders

Tags: reporting

I use the servlet.ReportList to get report information for reports in folders with AccessType = public. SFDC introduced a new Fine-Grained Sharing for Report and Dashboard Folders ([Summer 13 Release Notes](https://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf)), which doesn't seem to have a way to change the new folder types to anything but private access. How do I access basic report information for reports stored in these newfangled folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can set sharing only through the use of the [FolderShare](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_foldershare.htm) and [Folder](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_folder.htm) features of the metadata API. You can set the values through the CRUD- or File-based APIs, but you can read them only through the file-based APIs.